# NSTimer and NSRunLoop

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, cllocationmanager, nsrunloop

My app tracks a user with `CLLocationManager`. In the delegate call `didUpdateToLocation` I do all the fun stuff of saving their position. However, I needed a way to test if they had stopped. That away I could stop recording locations and consider their trip over. So I have a `NSTimer` in `CCLocationManager` that gets added and removed every time `didUpdateToLocation` is called. That away it will be initiated when the user stops and `CLLocationManager` stops getting called.

The only way that I could ever get the `NSTimer` to work is to do:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:userStoppedMovingTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Then to remove it:

```
[userStoppedMovingTimer invalidate];
```

I've never had to add timers like this in the past. Could someone shed some light as to why this is?

Comment: If you create the timer with `+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`, this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

> There are three ways to create a timer:
>
> 1. Use the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:` or
>      `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` class
>      method to create the timer and schedule it on the current run loop in
>      the default mode.
> 2. Use the `timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:` or
>      `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` class method
>      to create the timer object without scheduling it on a run loop. (After
>      creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling
>      the `addTimer:forMode:` method of the corresponding NSRunLoop object.)
> 3. Allocate the timer and initialize it using the
>      `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` method.
>      (After creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by
>      calling the `addTimer:forMode:` method of the corresponding `NSRunLoop`
>      object.)

You were probably using option 1 previously, and now you're using option 2 or 3.

Comment: Hi @Tom ,  in my case i have used run loop but it's not working when i install my application in iOS device ? So do you have any solution for that ?